# Как вызвать Java-метод из JavaScript?

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Прочитал документацию здесь: [How do I call Java methods from handwritten JavaScript or third party libraries?](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Client.html#How_do_I_call_Java_methods_from_handwritten_JavaScript_or_third). Но всё равно не пойму, как сделать следующее:

```
public static native void testBeforePaste(Element e, Runnable handler)  /*-{
  e.onbeforepaste = function() {

// хочется, чтобы здесь был вызов handler.run();

  };
}-*/;
```

Comment: Откуда вы хотите передавать параметры `Element e` и `Runnable handler`?

Comment: Они передаются из Java-кода (GWT-приложение).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите корректно *(хотя, пожалуй, это слишком сильное слово)* обработать `paste event`, то для этого не нужен `JSNI`.

Необходимо отнаследоваться от класса, которому направляется `paste event` *(например, `TextBox`).* Далее, в конструкторе нового класса сделать `sink` на соответствующий `event`, т.е написать `sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE)` и перегрузить соответствующий обработчик `onBrowserEvent`:

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);

    switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
        case Event.ONPASTE: {
            // Соответствующая обработка.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Небольшое замечание, насчет того, почему "корректно" - это сильное слово.

**Решение кроссбраузерно (с некоторыми ограничениями) для всех браузеров, кроме Opera.**

Таким образом, если есть возможность избежать работы с соответствующими `event'ами`, то стоит это сделать. Подробнее об `Opera` можно посмотреть в [**соответствующей таблице совместимости.**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html)

---

---

**Update: Не увидел, что именно `onbeforepaste`** *(расскажите, кстати, зачем вам это понадобилось)*

В таком случае и впрямь без `JSNI` не обойтись:

```
public native void addOnBeforePasteHandling(Element element) /*-{
        // Поскольку дальше используется замыкание.
        var thisHolder = this;

        element.onbeforepaste = function(e) {
            thisHolder.@org.package.YourClass::handleOnBeforePaste()();
        }
    }-*/;

public void handleOnBeforePaste() {
    Window.alert("onbeforepaste");
}
```

*Параметры можете прокинуть на свое усмотрение.*

Comment: Во-первых, мне нужно обработать `onbeforepaste`, а не `onpaste`. Он поддерживается только в WebKit и IE. Во-вторых, как обработать событие с помощью `sink + onBrowserEvent` и так понятно (и проблему не решает).

Comment: @wild frog Обновил ответ.

Comment: Нужно перенаправлять вставляемый текст в невидимое поле, делая его в `onbeforepaste` активным, и проводить над этим контентом некоторые операции. То же самое нужно для остальных методов работы с буфером. Реализовать этот "костыль" потребовалось только в Safari, так что об остальных браузерах можно не беспокоиться.